# How to run flash file in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: flash, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to embedding flash video in sharepoint 2013 through a webpart that's how I am incorporating it

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0"
                        width="320" height="240" id="VideoPlayer" align="middle">
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="*" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                        <param name="movie" value="<% =swfFileName%>" />
                        <param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                        <embed src="<% =swfFileName%>"
                            quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="320" height="240" name="VideoPlayer"
                            align="middle" allowscriptaccess="*" allowfullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                            pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
                    </object>
```

But it is not playing my video giving me an error failed to install add-on. Can anyone help me in this regard I am running sharepoint 2013 0n windows server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues getting this to work as well. After several attempts, this is what ended up working for me:

```
<iframe width="900" height="500" src="<full url of swf file>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I added the above to a Script Editor web part on the page, and everything worked well.